# "The query contains more than one unnamed or duplicate field name": Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm getting an error in Report Builder

> The query contains more than one unnamed or duplicate field name.
>   while every field has a prefix and I've not found any such case.

I've uploaded the .sql file here: 
http://www.filedropper.com/reportfraud

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you post the SQL code in your question?

Comment: @Sami Because "it appears your question is mostly a code..." and since the code is quite large, it would not be accepted unless I'd wirte something like tadtatdatdatdttda dadada tatatat daadadadaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 2):

`FPD_NotPaidYet` appears twice in the final select, once as a column, once as an alias